# preg_match doesn't behave as expected when validating windows filesystem path

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a regex that matches with Windows's filesystem file pathing:

```
c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd\a.php //valid match
c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd\a     //invalid match
```

with this pattern and code:

```
function validate_filepath()
{
    $view_path = 'c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd\a.php';

    // ^(?:[\w]\:)                  # matching drive
    //(?:\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+)+\\    # matching folder
    // [^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+\.(?:php)   # matching file and php extension
    $regex = '/^(?:[\w]\:)(?:\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+)+\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+\.(?:php)/mi';

    preg_match($regex, $view_path, $matches);
    return($matches[0]);
}
```

I've tried the pattern using https://regex101.com and it matches with the path, but it doesn't when using PHP's preg_match. Where did I make a mistake?

I haven't really looked how PHP handles string, but I tested using double backslash and correct pattern in regexonline, but php still returns null $matches

EDIT:
I'm using php-5.6.17

Comment: Tip: Have a look at the `x` regex modifier for inline commenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need a quadruple backslash here: inside the single quotes the double backslash is already an escaped single backslash. [Try printing the `$regex` variable]

So:

```
$regex = '/^(?:[\w]\\:)(?:\\\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+)+\\\\[^\\\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\.(?:php)/mi';
```

Or alternatively use the here more readable nowdoc syntax:

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
/^(?:[\w]\:)(?:\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+)+\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+\.(?:php)/mi
REGEX;
```

Comment: @thanksd Eih, yes. We definitely need an installer script creating this file containing octuple backslashes then.

Comment: Without useless things, the pattern can be shorten to: `$regex = '/^[A-Z]:(?:\\\\[^\\:*?"<>|\r\n]+)+\.php$/i';`